# Trigger a segue from Watch in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

Is it possible to trigger a segue in the iPhone app from the Watch code? I have been looking into OS2 and it says that data can be transferred while both apps are active, but want to know if it is possible to call code within the iPhone app from the Watch code.

Comment: Check this tutorial [http://www.raywenderlich.com/117329/watchos-2-tutorial-part-4-watch-connectivity](http://www.raywenderlich.com/117329/watchos-2-tutorial-part-4-watch-connectivity) to communicate. Once you receive a message you can do any action in iphone app if it is active.

Answer (score 3):

You can not push segue from WatchApp(Child Application) to iPhone App (Parent Application), but you can surely send data from Watch to iPhone and according to that data you can perform segue on iPhone Application.

To Send update from Apple Watch to iPhone App you have to implement `openParentApplication` in `WatchKit Extension`.

```
class func openParentApplication(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject], NSError?) -> Void)?) -> Bool
```

Create `NSDictionary` and pass that data using below code :

```
func updateInformationToParentApp(emergencyInfo : [NSObject : AnyObject]!){
  // Call the parent application from Apple Watch
  WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(emergencyInfo) { (returnUpdate, error) -> Void in
    if((error) == nil){
      print("Data send successfully");
    } else {
      print("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)");
    }
  }
}
```

Implement below method in `AppDelegate` to handle WatchApp update.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: ([NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void){
  NSLog("Handler Apple Watch Event ");
  watchEvent(userInfo, reply: reply);
}

func watchEvent(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) ->Void)!) {
  let dic = userInfo as NSDictionary;
  NSLog("dic %@", dic);

  // retrieved parameters from Apple Watch
  print(userInfo["Key"])
  //Perform Segue from Here according to Dictionary Info        
  //Pass back values to Apple Watch
  var returnUpdate = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
  let watchAppMessage = "Meesage Back To Apple Watch" as NSString;
  returnUpdate["message"] = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(watchAppMessage);
  reply(returnUpdate)   
}
```

Comment: Is there any examples in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

You can see `iPhone and iWatch contains different storyboards` and `different user interfaces`, so *segue from watch to iPhone is surely not possible* but you can manage something like that with *notifications* as if in iWatch some button is pressed, you can send notification to iPhone environment and it can trigger some action.